# How to change permission for dynamic routes?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, users

I am able to change permission callback perfectly for static urls: eg:
Works fine:

```
if ($route = $collection->get('entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection')) {
  foreach ($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
    $perms['administer ' . $vocabulary->id() . ' vocabulary terms'] = array(
      'title' => t('Administer %name vocabulary terms', array('%name' => $vocabulary->label())),
    );
    $route->setRequirement('_permission', 'administer ' . $vocabulary->id() . ' vocabulary terms');
  }
}
```

But same logic does not work for dynamic routes i.e route having a variable say taxonomy machine name.

Does not work:

```
if ($route = $collection->get('entity.taxonomy_term.add_form')) {
        foreach ($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
            if($taxonomy_vocabulary == $vocabulary->id) {
                $route->setRequirement('_permission', 'administer ' . $vocabulary->id() . ' vocabulary terms');
            }
        }
      }
```

Please suggest how to alter/change permission callback for taxonomy add/view etc routes.

Answer (score 4):

The `_permission` route setting isn't a callback function like the access callback in Drupal 7; it defines one or more permissions that are checked before granting access to the route. There's nothing dynamic about the setting. Adding one (or more) 'administer *taxonomy_id* vocabulary terms' permissions will restrict access if the user doesn't have those one or more permissions.

If you need to define a dynamic access check, you'll need to utilize `_custom_access` and define your own callback function that takes into account a specific permission check based on the context (see [*Structure of routes*](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643) for more information).

Comment: It still does not work.  I tried `services:
  access_check.entity_create:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Access\CustomAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@current_user']
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _entity_create_access }` & `public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
   
    return $account->hasPermission('Administer tags vocabulary terms');`

Comment: Troubleshooting from comments won't help much here, but I'll mention 2 things. You still need a `RouteSubscriber:: alterRoutes` function to add the your _custom_access function (not a yml definition). Also the_custom_access  function needs to return an `AccessResult` derived class, not a bool. See the [referenced link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122195) for more information.

Comment: I have tried `services:
  access_check.my_module_taxonomy:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Access\CustomAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@current_user']
    tags:
      - { name: access_check}`   , also did $route->setRequirement('_access', 'TRUE'); inside route alter . Still does not work. I have almost tried everything.